# Find Fourier Series of the function $f(x)=\sin x + \cos x$

Tags: fourier-series

I calculated the fourier series of the given function, but all of the fourier coefficient was 0, it sounds strange!

Comment: Could you show how the first two or three coefficients are zero?

Comment: No.  $\sin 0 + \cos 0 = 1$.  $\sin \pi + \cos \pi = -1$.

Comment: $\sin x + \cos x = \sqrt{2}\cos(x - \frac\pi 4)$ . This function's period is $2\pi$ .

Comment: sure, the period of the function is 2pi, for the first coefficient, we have the integral of the function on [0.2pi], also we know that integral of sinx and cosx on its period is 0, so the firs coefficient come to 0, for the second & third one, we just need the use of trigonometric identities to calculate the integral: 
an = (1/pi)integral(sinx cosnx + cosx cosnx) from 0 to 2pi = 
1/2pi {-(cos(n+1)x/n+1)-(cos(1-n)x/1-n)+(sin(1+n)x/1+n)+(sin(1-n)x/1-n)} from 0 to 2pi = 0 (n is a natural number)
we have the similar calculation for bn and it comes to 0 too

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)$ is already in Fourier Series representation.

But if you want to do the integral to get the coefficients:

$$
a_1=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\left(\sin x+\cos x\right)\cdot\cos\left(x\right)\right)dx = 1\\
b_1=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\left(\sin x+\cos x\right)\cdot\sin\left(x\right)\right)dx = 1
$$